# Content types and list forms

Tags: content-type, list, feature

I've encountered the strangest problem. I've got two features:

- `ContentTypes`: contains a couple of custom fields and a content type (based on plain ol' `0x01`) called `Withdrawals` that uses them. Scoped to Site.
- `Registration`: contains a `ListTemplate` and a `ListInstance` that just modifies a basic Custom List to enable content types and add my custom content type. Scoped to Web.

Here's what's happening. When I activate `ContentTypes`, the content type and field are deployed as expected into my site collection. When I activate `Registration`, the list is provisioned and the content type is added as expected.

When I try to add a new item to the list, the list form only shows the Title field from Item. Now, here's the weird part. If I add a second content type to the list (through the UI), the list form suddenly works correctly. This makes me think there's something wrong with my content type. Here's what I'm working with. Some names have been changed to protect the innocent.

```
<ContentType ID="0x0100B4366B5F6383463b8464DBD2EDD5E097"
           Name="Withdrawal"
           Description="Record of a team withdrawal"
           Hidden="False">
 <FieldRefs>
   <FieldRef ID="{CE8F7528-E643-4473-94E0-BAA57BD2F6E6}"/>
   <FieldRef ID="{E508D1FA-D3A5-4e91-828B-3BFB43D4F7C5}"/>
 </FieldRefs>
<XmlDocuments>
  <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
    <FormTemplates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
      <Display>ListForm</Display>
      <Edit>ListForm</Edit>
      <New>ListForm</New>
    </FormTemplates>
  </XmlDocument>
</XmlDocuments>
```

And here are the relevant bits of SCHEMA.XML:

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="Withdrawals" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="LTR" Url="Lists/Withdrawals" EnableContentTypes="TRUE" BaseType="0">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0100B4366B5F6383463b8464DBD2EDD5E097" />
      <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0120" />
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
      <Field ID="{CE8F7528-E643-4473-94E0-BAA57BD2F6E6}" Name="TeamName" StaticName="TeamName" DisplayName="Team Name" Type="Text">
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{E508D1FA-D3A5-4e91-828B-3BFB43D4F7C5}" Name="WithdrawalComments" StaticName="WithdrawalComments" DisplayName="Withdrawal Comments" Type="Note">
      </Field>
    </Fields>
```

It's also been added to the `ViewFields` in the two default views. What the heck am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is the kind of detail I like to see on questions.  Great work +1

Answer (score 3):

After hours of frustration, I finally figured out the problem. In the `<ContentType>` element, you need to specify *both the `ID` and `Name`* in each `FieldRef`. When I added the `Name` attribute to each `FieldRef`, those fields began to appear as expected on the item forms.

Comment: Cool thanks for letting us know.
Another thing that drove me crazy and took me hours to figure out was if you don't include the parenthesis in the field ID then nothing works either...